# Retrieve specific data from database and display

Tags: java, sql, database, prepared-statement

How to retrieve specific data from database and display?

```
    String sql = "Select Product_ID,Order_Quantity,Sub_Total from Order_Menu Where Order_ID='"+order_id_1+"'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){

        list.add(rs.getString("Product_ID"));
        list.add(rs.getString("Order_Quantity"));
        list.add(rs.getString("Sub_Total"));

        for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
            String item = list.get(i);
            System.out.println("Item" + i + ":" + item);
        }
```

I define the array

```
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

my output

```
Item0:P0001  
Item1:1  
Item2:37.0
Item0:P0001 
Item1:1 
Item2:37.0
Item3:P0002 
Item4:2 
Item5:666.0
```

My database only contains 2 items which is P0001 and P0002, how come the result will display 1 more item  
Sorry, I'm slightly confuse about array

Comment: First this not a array, It is array list

Comment: seems to be while loop not close

Answer (score 2):

You're printing the entire list contents every time you add a record from the result set.
In the first iteration, `list.size() == 3`, so it prints:

**Item0:P0001 Item1:1 Item2:37.0**

In the second iteration, `list.size() == 6`, so it prints:

**Item0:P0001 Item1:1 Item2:37.0 Item3:P0002 Item4:2 Item5:666.0**

Thereby making your eventual output:

**Item0:P0001 Item1:1 Item2:37.0 Item0:P0001 Item1:1 Item2:37.0 Item3:P0002 Item4:2 Item5:666.0**

Moving your for loop outside the while statement should fix it.

```
while(rs.next()){
  list.add(rs.getString("Product_ID"));
  list.add(rs.getString("Order_Quantity"));
  list.add(rs.getString("Sub_Total"));
}

for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
  String item = list.get(i);
  System.out.println("Item" + i + ":" + item);
}
```

Comment: solve it..thank you very much.. Just because of the loop. Now i understand, clear explain

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is not the correct way of using `PreparedStatement` . You should use it in following way:

```
String sql = "Select Product_ID,Order_Quantity,Sub_Total from Order_Menu Where Order_ID=?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(order_id_1);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Now, the reason for your output.

You are adding records in `list` assuming that at each index of list only one product is placing. But it is not the case. For example , if your program gets product `P0001` then you are adding `p001` at index `0` , Order_Quantity `1` at index `1` and subtotal `37` at index `2`. So , you are getting such output. I would suggest you to create a separate class for `Product`  as follows:

```
class Product
{
  String product_id;
  String order_quantity;
  String sub_total;
  public Product(String product_id, String order_quantity, String sub_total)
  {
    this.product_id = product_id;
    this.order_quantity = order_quantity;
    this.sub_total = sub_total;
  }
  public void setProduct_id(String product_id)
  {
    this.product_id = product_id;
  }
  public void setOrder_quantity(String order_quantity)
  {
    this.order_quantity = order_quantity;
  }
  public void setSub_total(String sub_total)
  {
    this.sub_total = sub_total;
  }
  public String getProduct_id()
  {
    return product_id;
  }
  public String getOrder_quantiy()
  {
    return order_quantity;
  }
  public String getSub_total() 
  {
    return sub_total;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if ( obj instanceof Product)
    {
        temp = (Product)obj;
        if (product_id.equals(temp.product_id))
        {
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
  @Override
  public int hashCode()//override it in such a way so that you get different hashCode for each product ID.
  {
    return product_id.hashCode();
  }
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "product_id:"+product_id+", order_quantity:"+order_quantity+", sub_total:"+sub_total;
  }
}
```

And finally, You can use the object of `Product` class as follows:

```
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
while(rs.next()){
 Product product = new Product(rs.getString("Product_ID"),rs.getString("Order_Quantity"),rs.getString("Sub_Total"));
  list.add(product);
 }
 for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
 Product item = list.get(i);
 System.out.println("Item" + i + ":" + item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing your list in between iterations.  This means that when you process the first row, your list will contain three items, when you display the second row, your list will contain the items from the first row and the second row...

Why don't you forget the list and just

```
for (int i = 0; rs.next(); ++i){

    System.out.println("Item " + i);
    System.out.println("Product ID    : " + rs.getString("Product_ID"));
    System.out.println("Order Quantity: " + rs.getString("Order_Quantity"));
    System.out.println("Sub_Total     : " + rs.getString("Sub_Total"));

}
```

and of course don't forget to wrap the whole thing in `try` `finally` and:

```
rs.close();
pst.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are iterating list out side the aray list

```
while(){
    //implementation
   }
   for(){
    //Iterate your list
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your database table is as follows:

```
Product_ID  Order_Quantity  Sub_Total 
P0001       1               37.0
P0002       2               666.0
```

Your while loop adds elements to your list as:

First iteration:

```
list=["P0001","1","37.0"]
```

Second iteration:

```
list=["P0001","1","37.0","P0002","2","666.0"]
```

So when the while loop executes the first time,
You are getting the output as:

```
Item0:P0001
Item1:1
Item2:37.0
```

In the second iteration, since list is ["P0001","1","37.0","P0002","2","666.0"],hence you get further output.

```
Item0:P0001
Item1:1
Item2:37.0
Item3:P0002
Item4:2
Item5:666.0
```

combining the above two outputs,you are getting:

```
Item0:P0001
Item1:1
Item2:37.0
Item0:P0001
Item1:1
Item2:37.0
Item3:P0002
Item4:2
Item5:666.0
```

So you need two dimensional data structure.I would suggest add a one dimensional array of strings to the list as:

```
String sql = "Select Product_ID,Order_Quantity,Sub_Total from Order_Menu Where    Order_ID='"+order_id_1+"'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    String[] row=new String[3]
    while(rs.next()){

        row[0]=rs.getString("Product_ID");
        row[1]=rs.getString("Order_Quantity");
        row[2]=rs.getString("Sub_Total");

        list.add(row);
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem..thanks for the clear explaination..and thanks for the help..now I understand why my output will be like that.